# Contents of Horizontal Scroller keeps stacking

Tags: html, css

(Note: I'm working on a assessment which is why it's for a pre-existing thing.)

**I have a horizontal media scroller which works however the contents keeps overlapping and I'm not sure why. I have to only use CSS and HTML too. I'm very new to this still so would really appreciate any help! Thankyou!**

HTML portion

```
<section>
    <h1 class=heading>Starring</h1>
    <div class="media-scroller">
      <div class="media-element">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjM5OTE1MjA3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTAxNjk4MDE@._V1_.jpg" alt="Tobin Bell" height="400px">
        <p>Tobin Bell</p>
      </div>
      <div class="media-element">
        <img src="https://scontent.fhlz4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/165941505_293315678847053_9188874086571008155_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=be3454&_nc_ohc=_CZiCziE2joAX-cUwyC&_nc_ht=scontent.fhlz4-1.fna&oh=00_AfAG7qwps8OiPXvCRF4sVYEwdgWNK8cIN_o_c_n9IyghxQ&oe=659FAD8E" alt="Shawnee Smith" height="400px">
        <p>Shawnee Smith</p>
      </div>
      <div class="media-element">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGQ5ZTI2OGYtZGZjNC00ZDg2LWE4MGItYTk4YTY2OGRiYTU2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjQwMDg0Ng@@._V1_.jpg" height="400px">
        <p>Synnøve Macody Lund</p>
      </div>
      <div class="media-element">
        <img src="https://www.gateworld.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/beach01.jpg" alt="Michael Beach" height="400px">
        <p>Michael Beach</p>
      </div>
      <div class="media-element">
        <img src="https://latw.org/sites/default/files/styles/artist_profile_l/public/Brand%2C%20Steven%202016%20Amadeus.jpg?itok=Mc-VVfFM" alt="Steven Brand" height="400px">
        <p>Steven Brand</p>
      </div>
      <div class="media-element">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZTM0NDY1ZjctNjFkMC00OTExLTgwNjAtYjE1M2NjNjYwNTQ2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjQwMDg0Ng@@._V1_.jpg" alt="Renata Vaca" height="400px">
        <p>Renata Vaca</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS portion

```
.media-scroller {
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 20%;
   
  padding: 30px;

  overflow-x: auto;
  overscroll-behaviour-inline: contain;
}

.media-element {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  gap: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #343434;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #851111,0 6px 18px 0 #B71717;
  min-width: 260px;
}

.media-element > img {
  inline: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 2/3;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpDku.png)

I've tried to cap the size of both the html element and the css part, tried aspect ratio  and using percentage instead of px. I also played with the padding in all instances in the css with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what's causing the issue is the percentage width of the columns (`grid-auto-columns: 20%;`) as it foces a certain % width which not necessarily matches the width of the tile. Try to remove it:

```
.media-scroller {
      display: grid;
      gap: 30px;
      grid-auto-flow: column;
      padding: 30px;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overscroll-behaviour-inline: contain;
}

.media-element {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-rows: min-content;
      gap: 4px;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: #343434;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #851111,0 6px 18px 0 #B71717;
      min-width: 260px;
}

.media-element > img {
      inline: 100%;
      aspect-ratio: 2/3;
      object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I can not believe that it was such an easy fix omg. Thankyou so much!!!

Comment: No problem :) Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped fix the issue